# Unable to send e-mail from within custom Symfony2 command but can from elsewhere in app

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

I have written a custom console command to query my database, produce a report and e-mail it to an address; however I can not seem to successfully send the e-mail. I can send e-mail fine from within normal controllers elsewhere within my application, and I can also send it from within my console command if I manually create and configure a Swift_Mailer instance and not get it via the container.

Here is a stripped down version of my console command:

```
<?php

namespace Foo\ReportBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class ExpiryCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('report:expiry')
            ->setDescription('Compile and send e-mail listing imminent expiries');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        /* ... */
        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('Expiry report')
            ->setFrom('DoNotReply@domain.com')
            ->setTo('recipient@domain.com')
            ->setBody($body);

        $mailer = $this->getContainer()->get('mailer');

/*      This works...
        $transport = \Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.domain.com', 25)
            ->setUsername('username')
            ->setPassword('password');
        $mailer = \Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
*/
        $result = $mailer->send($message);
        $output->writeln($result);
    }
}
```

Swiftmailer is configured to send via SMTP within my `app/config/config.yml` file (`delivery_address: dev@domain.com` is also set in `app/config/config_dev.yml`):

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: smtp
    host: smtp.domain.com
    username: username
    password: password
    spool:
        type: memory
```

When running the command, it prints `1` to the command line, which I assume it means it was successful. However I'm monitoring my mail server's logs at the same time, and it's not even connecting.

To confirm that my configuration was being loaded into the mailer, I changed the spool from `memory` to `file` and messages are being spooled to the file system when running the command and I can successfully flush the spool on the command line with `php app/console swiftmailer:spool:send`.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what's happening here, or any suggestions as to how I can debug it further? Nothing is appearing in my `app/logs/dev.log` file. I'm using Symfony 2.1.3-DEV.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From digging some Symfony and SwiftMailer code, I can see that the memory spool is flushed on the `kernel.terminate` event that occurs after a response was sent. I'm not sure it works for the commands, but I may be wrong.

Try adding this code at the end of your command and see if it helps:

```php
$transport = $this->container->get('mailer')->getTransport();
if (!$transport instanceof \Swift_Transport_SpoolTransport) {
    return;
}

$spool = $transport->getSpool();
if (!$spool instanceof \Swift_MemorySpool) {
    return;
}

$spool->flushQueue($this->container->get('swiftmailer.transport.real'));
```

Comment: Manually flushing the spool like this appears to work, I guess the `kernel.terminate` event isn't fired within console commands, then. Thanks!

Comment: Another option is disabling the spool from the config file, you can do this only for the command line. I did this as a temporary solution (yeah right) and it worked for me.

Comment: As always, great answer Elnur! :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of memory spool use file spool.
Modify your `app/config/config.yml`:

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: file, path: %kernel.root_dir%/spool }
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add this to the end of your execute action:

```
$container = $this->getContainer();
$mailer = $container->get('mailer'); 
$spool = $mailer->getTransport()->getSpool();    
$transport = $container->get('swiftmailer.transport.real');
$spool->flushQueue($transport);
```