# symfony2 email not sent in command

Tags: symfony, mailer

I'm developing one application with symfony2
In one side of application I'm sending emails, everything ok with this.
But now I create one command to run in crontab, but this dont send emails.
this is my command:
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Templating\EngineInterface;

class Sender {
    protected $em; protected $twig; protected $mailer;
    public function __construct($em, \Twig_Environment $twig, \Swift_Mailer $mailer) {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->twig = $twig;
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
    }

```
public function runSender() {
    $proj = $this->em->createQuery ...
    $maillist = $this->em->createQuery ...
$templateFile = "projectprojBundle:MailList:emailNew.html.twig";
$templateContent = $this->twig->loadTemplate($templateFile);
$body = $templateContent->render(array('proj' => $proj));

    foreach ($maillist as $m) {
    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()->setSubject('New projects')
    ->setFrom('...')->setTo($m['email'])
    ->setContentType('text/html')
    ->setBody(trim($body));
    $this->mailer->send($message);
    } } }
```

everything is ok with the queries, i tested.
and if i can send from other classes why i cant here?

Comment: Are you using spool memory? If yes this is the problem.

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122096/unable-to-send-e-mail-from-within-custom-symfony2-command-but-can-from-elsewhere

Comment: yes im using spool memory. and it works in other classes. but here its not working, i dont know why

Comment: could you clarify It works in other classes in cli or when you work in web. That a main point here. Check the link I posted.

Comment: when im working in web

Comment: when i change the spool to file, i cant sent email, even from web

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this at the end of the execution of your command:

```
$spool = $this->mailer->getTransport()->getSpool();
$transport = $this->getContainer()->get('swiftmailer.transport.real');

$spool->flushQueue($transport);
```

You have to extend the `ContainerAwareCommand` class to have access to the service container in your command.

Comment: And I got this error: Call to a member function getKernel() on a non-object

Comment: @BrunoRamalho Make sure you don't make in call to these methods in the `configure` method. All the code has to be called from the `execute` method or one of sub methods of this one.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your spool settings in config.yml

Use `spool: { type: memory }` to send e-mails instantly

```
# app/config/config.yml
swiftmailer:
    # ...
    spool: { type: memory }
```

Comment: im using spool type memory